# How to Format Sending Text in Whatsapp React Native

Tags: react-native, whatsapp

What I wanted is to send data that is written in object form in proper formate like stores have receipt my code is

```
 var date = new Date().getDate();
      const UploadDataCredentials = {
        user_id: user_id,
        user_detail: [Name, Phone, Address],
        order_detail: Data,
        total_price: TotalPrice,
        order_time: date,
        status: 'Pending',
      };

  Linking.openURL(`whatsapp://send?text=${JSON.stringify(UploadDataCredentials)}&phone=+923354584582`)
      props.navigation.replace(navigationstring.BOTTOMTABHOME);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so final i know answer of my question code is below

```
 onPress={() => {
        Linking.openURL(`whatsapp://send?text=${` Hey Dear in am intrusted in that Book  \n\n\n Name : ${item.name} \n\n Book Info : ${!!item.info ? item.info : item.desc} \n\n Price : ${price}`}&phone=+923354584582`)
      }}>
```

here /n represent Next line
you can formate whatsapp output message with any formate you want in text